# Php cannot read data sent via ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XMLHttprequest sends an empty post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10221974/xmlhttprequest-sends-an-empty-post)

Javascript part

[image]

PHP part

```
<?php echo $_REQUEST['p'] ?>
```

Just a stupid problem but i'm really stuck here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to set the content type, so php will know how to treat the request body

```
x.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Comment: works! thanx! but what's the difference between 'Content-type' and 'c-type'? are they the same?

Comment: @NajibRazak the only `c-type` I can think of is c-type strings, what `c-type` are you talking about.